# how to delete message(Items) from pubsub node using xmppframework in swift?

Tags: ios, swift, xmppframework

I have created chat app using xmppframework. I have implement chat functionality using pubsub node. I want to delete the particular message from pubsub node. How to implement it?

I have tried below code. But it delete Pubsub Node.

```
    let host = "YOUR_HOST_NAME"
    let serviceJID = XMPPJID(string: "pubsub.\(host)") 
    let xmppPubSub = XMPPPubSub(serviceJID: serviceJID, 
    dispatchQueue: DispatchQueue.main)
    xmppPubSub.addDelegate(self, delegateQueue: DispatchQueue.main)
    xmppPubSub.activate(appDelegate.xmppController.xmppStream)
    xmppPubSub.deleteNode("YOUR_PUBSUB_NODE_NAME")
```

But, I want to delete the message(i.e Item) form pubsub node.

Comment: can you elaborate more and give some code examples and how you've tried?

Comment: Can you please show an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) of your code where the not working parts can be reviewd?